# Get the absolute path of a input data file in unit test package

Tags: java

I have the following structure of the files (the folders are marked with - ):

```
-test
    -java
        -com.andrei.example.utils.data.input.impl
            UnitTest.java
            -template
                data.csv
```

I need to get the absolute path of the `data.csv` file from the `UnitTest.java` file. Here is what I tried

```
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String testDataFilePath = workingDir + File.separator + "/template/data.csv";
```

but `System.getProperty("user.dir");` returns the root project directory, and I would not like to hardcode the rest of the path to the file.

I have also tried this:

```
    File file = new File("./template/data.csv");
    file.getAbsolutePath();
```

But this one returns me as well the root project dir + `./template/data.csv`.

I am unable to get the absolute path to the `data.csv` file, because the package of the `UnitTest.java` does not contain the `test.java. ...`.

How could I get the absolute path of the `data.csv` file?

Thank you!

Comment: You should not put data files in your classpath and expect good results.   It is likely your IDE is not even including these in your product when it builds.  If you are using something like Maven, use a resource directory instead.

Comment: Put another way, the runtime working directory "./" is /not/ going to be your classpath, in general.  And it certainly isn't a subdirectory of your classpath that somehow magically maps to the package directory of the 'currently executing' class, or something....

Comment: @BadZen that file is exclusively for testing, that's why I would like to keep it in the unit test package

Answer (score 0):

¿Have you tried with `JFileChooser`?

```
JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
        jfc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\hash\\tareas"));
        jfc.showOpenDialog(jfc);
        String ruta = jfc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
```

For example with `setCurrentDirectory` you put an specific route to open the `openDialog` but you made a selection graphically. Then you get the `AbsolutePath` in `jfc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();`. Another option could be using this format for the path `"C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\hash\\tareas\\template\\data.csv"`.